# Can i launch firefox with selenium 3.3.0 version without geckodriver

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I need launch Firefox browser with selenium 3.3.0 version.

Is any way to launch without geckodriver ?

Answer (score 1):

For Selenium 2.x later versions it is mandatory to use gecko-driver for Firefox browser. If you don't want to use gecko-driver use selenium 2.x(2.53) version

Comment: How can I replace Selenium 2.53?

Comment: If you are using maven, just change version in pom.xml file to newer version that you want to maintain..